# PHP/Laravel date based ID - how to make it waterproof?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a date based ticket ID for my Laravel system, like:

```
2103 0001
2103 0002
2103 0003
```

And then next month:

```
2104 0001
2104 0002
2104 0003
```

I've getted it working using this:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$repairCount = Repair::where('code', 'LIKE', date('ym') . ' %')->count();
$repairCount++;

$repairID = $date->format('ym') . " " . str_pad($repairCount,4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

But this isn't completely 'waterproof'. When I delete a repair (not the last one). It counts the numbers and then takes the last one (so you get duplicate ID).

How to improve this?

Comment: Fetch the last one and increase it by one?

Comment: But then it always increases by one, also if month is changed.
If new month begins it should begin at 0001 again.

Comment: Fetch the last one in a given month then. I do hope you're storing a date field separately.

Comment: You could mark your repairs as in-active instead of deleting.

Comment: @El_Vanja nope, don't have the date field stored seperately, because then you don't have a completely unique code thing (or how I can explain it).

Comment: @cOle2 I think that is not GDRP proof in our country.

Comment: Exactly what prevents you to keep an additional column with the actual date? As soon as you are not storing date as an actual date, you are just waiting to be in a world of pain when you start writing queries that filter by date. Create your unique key with the date as part of it, but also store the actual creation date in a date column. You'll thank yourself in the future.

Comment: Oh sorry. There is a created_at field, do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, you could use that. You filter by that column with the desired year and month and fetch the latest one from that subset. If you get a value, increase by one, if not then start at 0001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I covered any issues completely, by using this (based on last()):

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$repairID = Repair::where('code', 'LIKE', date('ym') . ' %')->get()->last();
if ($repairID != null) 
{
    $repairID = substr($repairID->code, 5);
    $repairID++;
}
else
{
    $repairID = 1;
}
```

Then save it with:

```
$date->format('ym') . " " . str_pad($repairID,4,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

Please let me know if this can cause some unwanted/unexpected behaviour.